# Method/Plugin/Hack to Start a Post with an Writing Outline?

Tags: plugins, posts, automation

I'm looking for a method/plugin/hack to auto-insert an outline when I start a new post in Wordpress. I've searched online for ideas as well as the [WP Plugin repo](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/) with no luck.

Essentially, many of my posts have a similar structure, and it would be nice not to have to paste it each time, but to have it embedded in the body of the "Add New Post" page. Of course, it should be editable.

Comment: Thanks all for the answers, all excellent and wish I had thought of them. In the end, Mike's plugin really hit the spot for simplicity and relevancy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very similar to this question:

- [**Creating a Custom Post Type for Inserting Preset Content into Post & Pages?**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1515/creating-a-custom-post-type-for-inserting-preset-content-into-post-pages)

You might find the solution to be what you need; I extended my [**WP Boilerplate Shortcode**](http://mikeschinkel.com/downloads/wp-boilerplate-shortcode-v1.0.5.zip) plugin to meet the needs of the person asking the question; you might find the solution fits your needs as well.

Comment: Mike - fantastic! I absolutely love it, and it has the flexibility to accommodate multiple templates/boilerplates. 

I only have very minor piece of feedback: I can't do an insert of a boilerplate if I'm in the HTML mode of the editor. - Khalid

Comment: Hi *@Khalid* Well you know what the doctor would tell Henny Youngman, right? (j/k:  http://hubpages.com/hub/Henny-Youngman-King-of-One-Liners :-)  I'll look at it next time I'm in the code but that plugin is unfortunately not a huge priority for me as I'm desperately trying to get other work done. Hopefully you can live with it as is?

Comment: absolutely. Just thought you might like to know. Thanks again. Best, - Khalid

Answer (score 1):

Create new page with your outline, save it as draft. I called it "Outline".

Then drop this in functions.php of your theme (can be packed as plugin if needed).

```
add_filter( 'default_content', 'default_post_outline' );

function default_post_outline( $post_content ) {

$page = get_page_by_title( 'Outline' );

if( isset( $page ) )
return $page->post_content;

return $post_content;
}
```