# Prepopulating a specific page template with HTML/CSS

Tags: customization, page-template

So, I'm trying to prepopulate a specific page with HTML/CSS every time the page template is used. I've found [this thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1439/pre-populating-the-page-post-content-editor-with-html-snippets) that was very helpful with how to do it, and [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/238640/what-does-is-page-template-compare-against) was very helpful on clearing up the confusion about how to use the parameter for the function. But I cannot get the first `if` statement to be read, here is my function:

```
/* Fill Assessments page with HTML contents */
add_filter('default_content', 'my_editor_content');
function my_editor_content( $content )
{
    if (is_page_template(ABSPATH.'wp-content/themes/sydney/page-templates/page_assessments.php'))
    {
        $content = 'HELL YEAH';
    }
    else
    {
        $content = file_get_contents(ABSPATH.'wp-content/themes/sydney/assessments.html');
    }
    return $content;
}
```

But I can't get the file to read the first `if` statement. I've also tried:

```
if (is_page_template('path/page-template.php')
```

But nothing worked to read that so far. How can I achieve it? Thanks!

Comment: have you read https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page_template/#page-template-in-subdirectory ? in your case this could be: `is_page_template( 'page-templates/page_assessments.php' )`

Comment: Do you want to add them to an entire page or just a section of that page?

Comment: @NathanielFlick whole page should be fine.

Comment: @Michael I think my post references exactly that, I have tried exactly that, without using `ABSPATH.` I don't know what exactly is wrong here.

Comment: this filter `default_content` is not usefull for you because it is called when you click on "new page" then before the user choose the template. another solution could be JavaScript that add content when the user change the template.

Comment: Nice. Thanks! I really needed that clarification, @mmm. I'll comeback with how I solved it in the future, hopefully.